# WebSupergoo ABCpdf10 PDF Exception Failed to add HTML

Tags: pdf-generation, abcpdf

We are getting following exception. It is working fine on local. Can anyone provide any suggestion?

```
9528 19:15:28 ERROR EDComponents > EDPDFGenerator Exception
Exception: WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10.Internal.PDFException
Message: Failed to add HTML: Page load failed. The specified file is unavailable. This could be related to network or permission issues, or OnLoadScript evaluation error.
Source: ABCpdf
   at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddUrlHtml(String urlOrHtml, Boolean isHtml, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
   at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url, Boolean paged, Int32 width, Boolean disableCache)
   at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Doc.AddImageUrl(String url)
   at K2Intelligence.Web.UI.Controllers.BioController.GenerateDefautPDF()

Nested Exception

Exception: WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10.Internal.PDFException
Message: Page load failed. The specified file is unavailable. This could be related to network or permission issues, or OnLoadScript evaluation error.
Source: ABCpdf
   at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf10.Internal.Gecko.GeckoWorker.AddImageUrl(String url, Double pageWidthMm, Double pageHeightMm, AddImageUrlOptions options, IProgressStreamEx stream)
```